# Submatrix of given size with largest sum

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a N*N grid filled with all zeros. Then I update N random points on it and set their value to any number greater than equal to 1. Also, given is a value of "L".

We want to find a sub-matrix of size L*L in the grid such the the sum of the elements in the sub-matrix is maximum. If there are multiple answers, possible output the coordinates of any such sub-matrix.

Constraints:
1 <= N <= 50000, 1 <= L <= 50000.

I know how to solve the problem in O(N<sup>2</sup>) considering all sub-matrices of sizes L*L, using prefix sums to calculate the sum. But the problem here is the I cannot declare such a large matrix due to constraints on N.

Is there any efficient way to tackle this problem? Any help would be grateful.

Comment: This is an active challenge: https://www.codechef.com/AUG16/problems/MAXGRID  Codechef usually publishes an explanation of the solution once the competition is finished.

Comment: Think about how you would calculate a sliding window sum in 1D using O(1) storage and extend that approach to 2D using O(N) storage

Comment: @samgak thanks for the help, but the complexity still remains O(n^2) in your case. Am I right? Can we improve the complexity too given that only 1/L of the grid is only filled?